# query document which has particular word at last index of that field

Tags: solr, solrj

I have a field with `TextField` data type

I want to search if it has particular word at last index of that field,

For example.

my field is `title` with value `Elligator Red Lace Men's Running Sports Shoes`

Now I want to search for documents with which has `Shoes` as last word in the title.

Comment: `TextField` is the class or input data type for a `fieldType`. What is the `fieldType` for the data?

Comment: @YoungHobbit yes its class

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried search by SOLR regex ? (supported by SOLR 4.0+.)

```
q=title:/.*Shoes/
```

For this, title field must by of type `StringField`, so it is not tokenized.

Comment: thanks for answer but i am not sure if i can use wildcard at begin due to performance issue

Comment: For better performance, you can extract last token before you import data into solr and put it into its own field. Then you can query this field.

Comment: that's what i have thought if i don't get any direct solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use [RegEx CharFilter](http://www.solr-start.com/javadoc/solr-lucene/org/apache/lucene/analysis/pattern/PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory.html) to basically add a boundary marker at the end (so, replace *$* with *[[END]]*). *$* here is a regular expression marker for the end of line, just to be clear.

Then, after tokenization, you replace any token that does not have that marker with empty string, using [RegEx TokenFilter](http://www.solr-start.com/javadoc/solr-lucene/org/apache/lucene/analysis/pattern/PatternReplaceFilterFactory.html) (Token, not Char now). Then, you have another one of those to just strip off your boundary marker. You end up with a bunch of empty tokens (which I believe are ignored) and your single last-word token. I'd recommend doing that in a copyField and use that as a boost.

You do need to be careful that your input stream actually has your last token right at the end before you add the boundary marker to it and that your boundary marker text is not something that tokenizer will break at. So, you may need to preprocess your string with another Char Filter or even on a client.

Comment: thanks for answer but it looks little  complicated but i will check this

Comment: The other option is to just regex a copy to keep your last token. But then you need to figure out the boundary condition (whitespace? non-latin characters? etc) by yourself.